# RedirectToAction to another Controller and passing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in C# and espacially in ASP.NET MVC.

I have my **HomeController**, which contains this method:

```
public ActionResult Error(Error error)
{
    return View(error);
}
```

Now I have another Controller, which have the following line inside:

```
return RedirectToAction("Error","Home", new { Error = (new Error("ErrorName","ErrorDescription"))} );
```

As you might notice, I am trying to pass an Error object to the other controller, which then should pass it to the View.

The Error class I have written on my own, nothing spectacular:

```
public class Error
{
    public String name {  get; private set; }
    public String description {  get; private set; }
    public int number {  get; private set; }

    public Error(String name, String description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        number = 0;
    }
}
```

My problem ist that every time I try to access the error Variable in the HomeController, it is `null`.
I have already googled an found some posts, but I don't understand, why my code isn't working.
There are no errors, just this null value object..
I Appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Because you have `private set` on all your properties (the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the properties. And you also need to include a parameter-less constructor

Comment: Are you sure you can pass a [serialized object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot initialize an instance or your `Error` class based on the query string parameters because you have `private set` on all your properties.

Your model should be

```
public class Error
{
  public String name {  get; set; }
  public String description {  get; set; }
  public int number {  get; set; }

  public Error() // you must add a parameter-less constructor
  {
  }

  public Error(String name, String description)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    // number = 0; // no need for this - the default is 0
  }
}
```

You can also use

```
return RedirectToAction("Error","Home", new { name = "ErrorName", description = "ErrorDescription"});
```

and delete both constructors

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I removed the `private` statements and added a parameterless constructor, but when I try to access the parameter in `HomeController`s `Error(Error error)` method, I still get an exception.
I trird `String test = error.name;`...
do you have any other ideas? Thanks until here :)

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` is thrown in the line, because the `error` variable is `null`

Comment: I have just tested this and it works fine. Have your tried `RedirectToAction()` as per my last snippet

Comment: Yes it works - thanks! But I now dont really understand, how the compiler knows, that he must create an Error Object - do you know what I mean?
I just found out that is has no effect when I write `new Error {name="...",description="..."}`

Comment: When you do `RedirectToAction()` you not actually passing the model to the `Error()` method. The `RedirectToAction()` internally generates query string values (your url would be `/Home/Error?name=ErrorName&description=ErrorDescription`). Then in the `Error()` method, the `DefaultModelBinder` first initializes the method parameters (i.e. your `Error` class) - which is why you need a parameter-less constructor, then it sets the properties - which is why you need public setters.

Comment: Okay, now there ist not that much "magic" on this than before :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass complex objects in an url like that. You will have to send its constituent parts:

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{

   // Here user object with updated data

   return RedirectToAction("Error","Home", new { 
        name = "ErrorName", 
        description = "ErrorDescription", 
        number = 0
   });
}
```

Comment: Of course you can pass complex objects (just so long as their properties are value types - which OP's are)

Comment: This works fine - thank you! But now I don't understand how the compiler knows that he has to create an Error object - does he "look" in the HomeControllers method?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "error" in lower case when you name the anonymous parameter.

```
return RedirectToAction("Error","Home", new { error = (new Error("ErrorName","ErrorDescription"))} );
```

I believe the parameters are passed by name, and now he can't link "Error" to parameter name of your method.

Comment: Te `DefaultModelBinder` is NOT case sensitive - this make no difference at all