# ASP.NET MVC 5 - RedirectToAction with custom type passes empty object

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirecttoaction, custom-type

I've got a situation that I don't understand. I'm developing a small web application, which simulates poolbillard game process. I've got two actions, first is an action responsible for gathering input from user, second calculates necessary data:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInput(UserInputViewModel inputParameters)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Play", new { inputParameters });
}

public ActionResult Play(UserInputViewModel playParameters)
{  
    PoolTableConfig config = CreatePoolTableConfig(playParameters);
    PoolTable poolTable = new PoolTable(config);
    PocketName resultPocketName = poolTable.Play();
    IEnumerable<Point> crossPoints = poolTable.CrossPoints;

    ViewBag.ResultPocketName = resultPocketName;
    ViewBag.CrossPoints = crossPoints;

    return View();
}

private PoolTableConfig CreateConfig(UserInputViewModel input)
{
    return new PoolTableConfig()
    {
       Width = input.Width,
       Height = input.Height,
       BallPointX = input.BallPointX,
       BallPointY = input.BallPointY,
       VectorX = input.VectorX,
       VectorY = input.VectorY
    };
}
```

And UserInputViewModel looks like this:

```
public class UserInputViewModel
{
    
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify width.")]
[ProperWidth(ErrorMessage = "Width must be an even number.")]
[Range(300, 700)]
public uint Width { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify height.")]
[Range(150, 500)]
public uint Height { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify ball position X.")]
[Display(Name = "Ball position X")]
[ProperBallPosition("Width", ErrorMessage = "Ball position X cannot be equal or higher than pool table width.")]
public uint BallPointX { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify ball position Y.")]
[Display(Name = "Ball position Y")]
[ProperBallPosition("Height", ErrorMessage = "Ball position Y cannot be equal or higher than pool table width.")]
public uint BallPointY { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify vector X.")]
[Display(Name = "Vector X value")]
[Range(-1000, 1000)]
public int VectorX { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please specify vector Y.")]
[Display(Name = "Vector Y value")]
[Range(-1000, 1000)]
public int VectorY { get; set; }
}
```

As you see I'm passing custom type (viewmodel) from `UserInput()` action to `Play()` action. The `inputParameter` variable in `UserInput()` action has proper values, but when program goes to the `Play()` action it is null or empty (with default values of types contained in object).

As I understand default ASP.NET model binding verifies what properties does custom object need and searches for them in http header sent from the client. I stick to the standard ASP.NET validation schema, so I don't understand why does my app have a problem with translating http header parametrs to a .NET object. When I replace custom type with predefined type (i.e. string) everything is as it should be.

My question is: Why ASP can't generate proper object from http header in this situation?

Comment: Yes, I did. Result was the same.

Comment: I dont think you can pass objects like that

Comment: @helvy91 sorry I didn't saw it is get action. You can not pass object to another action. So solution is either keep in sesion/tempdata/db and retrieve it into another section.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this

```
return RedirectToAction("Play", "ControllerName", inputParameters);
```

Also could you not just do the calculations that are done in `Play` inside the `UserInput ActionResult` and then just return what ever view you were going to return in the `Play ActionResult`?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInput(UserInputViewModel inputParameters)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)return View();

    PocketName resultPocketName;
    IEnumerable<Point> crossPoints;

    PoolTable poolTable = new PoolTable((int)inputParameters.Width, (int)inputParameters.Height, (int)inputParameters.BallPointX, (int)inputParameters.BallPointY, inputParameters.VectorX, inputParameters.VectorY);
    resultPocketName = poolTable.Play();
    crossPoints = poolTable.CrossPoints;

    ViewBag.ResultPocketName = resultPocketName;
    ViewBag.CrossPoints = crossPoints;

    return View("ViewName", whatEverModelYouNeed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
return Play(inputParameters);
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Play", new { inputParameters });
```

-- Edit

Good to know that you can't pass object to GET method, and it's not possible to use POST either because RedirectToAction returns 302 to the browser which means the browser will make GET request!

The solution I wrote above 'll do the trick but it's hacky and not recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, but I've just found the most satisfying answer myself :). I used RouteValueDictionary(). UserInput() action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UserInput(UserInputViewModel inputParameters)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Play", "Home" , new RouteValueDictionary(inputParameters));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to issue the redirect command and pass data you will use TempData. This post breaks it down better than I could without plagiarism [Passing object in RedirectToAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction)