# How can I pass my object with RedirectToAction?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have a `SubmitComment` Action and a `Message` class. I want to use `Message` class for sending that the action is done successfully or not, but `Message.Result` is false and `Message.Text` is null when I check them in `ShowProduct` action.

```
public class Message
{
    public bool Result { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

My `SubmitCommen`t Action:

```
public ActionResult SubmitComment(int productId, string comment, string nickName)
{
        try
        {
            var productCM = new ProductCM
            {
                //I make my prodcut comment object here
            };
            storesDB.ProductCMs.Add(productCM);
            storesDB.SaveChanges();

            Message message = new Message
            {
                Result = true,
                Text = "Your comment successfully registered."
            };

            return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct", new { id = productId, message });
        }
        catch (//if any exeption happend)
        {
            Message message = new Message
            {
                Result = false,
                Text = "Sorry your comment is not registered."
            };

            return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct", new { id = productId, message });
        }
}
```

My `ShowProduct` Action:

```
public ActionResult ShowProduct(int? id, message)
{
    ViewBag.Message = message;

    var model = storesDB.Products;

    return View(model);
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `catch (//if any exeption happend)` -> `catch (Exception ex)` or simply `catch (Exception)`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597863/passing-object-in-redirecttoaction

Comment: what is the problem, are you getting empty values for id and message or just for message. try using RouteValueDictionary to pass complex objects.

Comment: Yes I think I should better to use RoutValueDictionary @hazimdikenli

Comment: Yes I think I should better to use RoutValueDictionary  @Mikev

Comment: a redirect kills the current request (and sends HTTP status code 302 Object Moved to the client), then creates a new request on the server to serve the redirected view. In this scenario you need to use TempData.   Syntax: TempData["Message"] = myMessage;

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass object with `RedirectToAction`. Alternatively, instead of `return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct", new { id = productId, message })` use `return ShowProduct(productId,message);` as follows:

```
Message message = new Message
{
    Result = true,
    Text = "Your comment successfully registered."
};

return ShowProduct(productId,message);
```

Comment: It works but I want to show ShowProduct view after that I submited the comment, but It want to show SubmitComment View!!! Can you help about that?

Comment: @FarshadShahsavari Mark it answer and better ask a different question with the new requirement clearly. I shall try level best to help you.

Answer (score 0):

For `RedirectToAction`, it will pass the parameter as query string, and you could not pass the embeded object.

Try to specify the properties like

```
return RedirectToAction("ShowProduct", new { id = productId, message.Result, message.Text });
```

For `return ShowProduct(productId,message);`, specify the ViewName like

```
public ActionResult ShowProduct(int? id, Message message)
{
    ViewBag.Message = message;

    return View("ShowProduct");
}
```