# how to pass a Model from a controller to another controller

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm starter in .NET MVC. I want to pass a model from one controller to another controller, model contain a password. My first controller is auth method, in that I used Claims, but another controller is a vote method there I need to Post an ID, Password and Vote. Password I need in vote controller for voting confirmation in database. 
My code: 
My model:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string IDNP { get; set; }
    public string VnPassword { get; set; 
}
```

My first controller:

```
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(LoginModel model)
    {

        var data = new LoginData();
        data.IDNP = model.IDNP;
        data.VnPassword = model.VnPassword;

        var response = await session.Login(data);
        if (response.Status == true)
        {
            var authclaims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, data.IDNP),
            };

            var authIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(authclaims, "User Identity");

            var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] {authIdentity});
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Vote",new{pass=data.VnPassword});
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My second controller:

```
public class VoteController : Controller
{
    private IVote connection;
    public VoteController()
    {
        var bl = new BusinessManager();
        connection = bl.GetVote();
    }
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(VoteModel vote)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
        var voteindex = new VoteData();
        voteindex.IDNP = identity.Name;
        voteindex.VnPassword = ;
        voteindex.Party = vote.Party;

        var response = await connection.Vote(voteindex);
        if (response.Status == true)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Auth");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you want to store password with vote? You should call business layer method to store vote from Auth Controller after login.

Comment: just for clarity, you are trying to hit the `HttpPost` version of `Index`?

Comment: Also, what does your `VoteModel` class look like?

Comment: @PatrickMcvay I deleted IActionResult then I posted. VoteModel contain public string Party { get; set; }. It's a party that user choice.

Comment: i feel a joke comming how do you ask controller to send data to another controller you use Interfaces eg watch king Arthur movie and you get this

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's a bad idea to send Id and Password to another controller. It conflicts SRP rule.
You should have only one controller that gets and uses password.

However, if you want to use this action, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11873145/5836364)