# Redirect to action pass complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I want to pass to RedirectToAction model with List type property

For example, I have this simple model:

```
public class OrgToChooseFrom
    {
        public string OrgId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

And complex model as this:

```
public class SelectCounteragentViewModel
    {
        public List<OrgToChooseFrom> Counteragents { get; set; }
        public OrgToChooseFrom SelectedOrg { get; set; }
    }
```

When I pass simple model with RedirectToAction every value is in place

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ConfirmChoice(OrgToChooseFrom vm)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
```

But when I try to pass complex model SelectCounteragentViewModel, there are empty list and null for the "SelectedOrg" field

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SelectFromCAOrganizations(SelectCounteragentViewModel vm)
        {
            return View(vm);
        }
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You can not pass model in RedirectToAction  you have to pass valid parameters or you can use TempData for that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RedirectToAction(..) with complex deep object fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352015/redirecttoaction-with-complex-deep-object-fails)

Comment: Are all actions in the same controller or different?

Comment: @KiranJoshi TempData is how I solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` cannot pass complex model.You can try to use `TempData` as
`Kiran Joshi` said.Here is a demo:

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
           
            SelectCounteragentViewModel vm = new SelectCounteragentViewModel { Counteragents = new List<OrgToChooseFrom> { new OrgToChooseFrom { OrgId ="1", FullName = "d" } }, SelectedOrg = new OrgToChooseFrom { OrgId = "1", FullName = "d" } };
            TempData["vm"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
            return RedirectToAction("SelectFromCAOrganizations", "ControllerName");
        }
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SelectFromCAOrganizations()
        {
            SelectCounteragentViewModel vm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SelectCounteragentViewModel>(TempData["vm"].ToString());
            return View(vm);
        }
```