# Examples of a MailManager specfic to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, email

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296680/net-mvc-call-method-on-different-controller) introduced two different approaches to a fundamental need of every web-app - email-based interactions with a site's users - the uses the term *MailManager*. I'm currently suffering the pain of a poorly designed, first gen attempt at generating (and sending, and logging, and searching) things like invoices, notifications, followups and tracking. Stuff that wasn't in the original spec. I understand the need to refine things to use a more generalized controller.

So i'd like to study how this functionality has been implemented in other projects. Is this role generic or well defined enough that perhaps one of the codeplex or git projects (or an MVC-based tutorials) has a fleshed out example?