# MVC 3 get ActionResult of an action that is defined on a different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reflection, asp.net-mvc-routing, controller-factory

**Problem:**

What I need is something similar to @Html.RenderAction("action","controller") , but one that I can use from inside a different controller. This for example:

```
public class FirstController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult GetErDone()
   {
        return View();
   }
}

public class SecondController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        ActionResult coolResult = 
               Helper.GetActionResult("GetErDone", "FirstController");

        return View();
   }
}
```

**Progress:**

I have begun to strip/reform the actual @Html.Action() method but it really has too many internal helper dependencies and I am thinking this shouldn't be that tough. What I have so far is:

```
    private void TestCreateActionFromDifferentController(RouteValueDictionary routeValues, string controllerName, string actionName)
    {
        var httpContext = this.HttpContext;
        var routeData = this.RouteData;
        routeData.Values["action"] = (object)actionName;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controllerName))
            routeData.Values["controller"] = (object)controllerName;

        IController myController = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory().CreateController(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData) , "staticpages");
    }
```

This works partially of course (minus the many shortcomings like area data tokens etc) but still there is no way other than reflection to get to the `MyActionResult` object.

**Summary:**

When inside a controller, what is a way to get an ActionResult from an action that is defined on a different controller, ?

**Update:**

More specifically, I am trying to use something like System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ChildActionMvcHandler but one that doesnt execute, rather it returns the ActionResult

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET MVC Call method on different controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296680/net-mvc-call-method-on-different-controller)

Comment: Thanks for the links, however: I dont need to `Render` a `View`, I need to create an instance of an `ActionResult` object (more similar to this is to render an Action - Still different from rendering a View). Also, I dont need to return a string, I need to return an ActionResult (which needs the controllerContext thus it cannot be refactored). This is very specific and very different

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you trying to make a Mash up of multiple actions?

Comment: Main design reason is I want to manage dependencies at runtime. Imagine a dependency resolution tier that sits right before presentation tier (before sending to views)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to return a `ActionResult` from a another `controller`.  Possibly you could provide more details to understand us problem domain.

I think You could consider to use `BaseController` and declare a Static Method `GetErrorDone` with return results.

This method can be called from All `Child Controllers`.

---

> OR 2nd Answer

Consider to just Redirect it to required Action using **[Controller.RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx)**

```
e.g. RedirectToAction("action name" "controller Name")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however a shared method doesnt help my case. I need to create many parts then compose them.

Comment: An action result represents a "command" that the framework will perform on behalf of the action method. What is your command? What it will return back to View?

Comment: This is exactly the problem - I dont want the ActionResult to return directly to View, I want the ActionResult to return to Controller. I just want to move the responsibility of gathering all the child ActionResult , at the controller level, not the View level. iE: Instead of (At razor) @Html.Action([get main menu]), @Html.Action([get side bar]) etc.... I want to get all the components at a main Controller