# Redirect in ASP MVC 4 without a 302 status code

Tags: redirect, asp.net-mvc-4

How to redirect page in ASP MVC 4?

I've tried `Redirect`, `RedirectPermanent`, `RedirectToAction`, and so on. But it is like HTTP Redirect (using `http-equiv refresh`), not Header Redirect. It will display Header Status 302 first, then redirect. I want header redirect like in `php header('location:/');`

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    UtilsHelper.NoCache();
    session.Destroy();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: Call the controller method directly.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296680/net-mvc-call-method-on-different-controller) for examples.

Comment: But, I want to redirect, not show result from different controller's method.

Comment: No you don't.  If you really wanted to redirect, you'd live with the 302.  It's semantically correct.

Comment: Uh, what about logout redirect?

Comment: What about it?  Return an appropriate View.

Answer (score 3):

If you are really worried about the redirect code you could control it at a lower level.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SignOut()
{
    UtilsHelper.NoCache();
    session.Destroy();
    HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302; //change it to 301?
        HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = "/";
        HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```

Im not sure what is the issue with 302 here?

Comment: what about the return value?

Comment: @BiasTegaralaga Something should be return but it will redirect first so return value doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect

See
[How to simulate Server.Transfer in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799511/how-to-simulate-server-transfer-in-asp-net-mvc)

for further information