# What is the best approach to share data between controllers in ASP .NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult AControllerAction()
      {
          if (// BControllerAction reported an error somehow )
          {
                ModelState.AddModelError("error-key", "error-value");
          }
          ...
      }
}

public class BController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult BControllerAction()
      {
          try{Something();}
          catch(SomethingExceprion)
          {
              // here I need to add error info data,
              // pass it to AController and redirect to
              // AControllerAction where this error will be added 
              // to model state
          }
      }
}
```

I think I can do something like:

```
public ActionResult BControllerAction()
{
     try{Something();}
     catch(SomethingException)
     {
         var controller = new AController();
         controller.ModelState.AddModelError("error-key", "error-value");
         controller.AControllerAction();
     }
}
```

But I suggest it will be architecture breaking approach, and I don't want to do like that. Is there some simpler and safer way, except passing model object?

Comment: Your approach is correct.
You can execute another controller and return its ActionResult. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409049/net-mvc-call-a-controller-action-from-another-controller-action)

Comment: See also, for example, [.NET MVC - Call a controller Action from another controller action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409049/net-mvc-call-a-controller-action-from-another-controller-action). If you have logic that two controllers need, then that logic either doesn't belong in a controller or it does, but then in a shared base class.

Comment: Are you using ModelState to log exceptions?

Comment: @Forty-Two, exception will be logged in `catch(SomethingException)` block by logger (I simplified this details to focus on main problem I'm interested in), I just need to inform user about this error by another controller's action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a redirect to AControllerAction. You can use the TempData dictionary (similar to ViewData) to share data across such a call (data stored this way will persist to the next request in the same session, as explained [in this blog post](http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/)).

Example:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult AControllerAction()
      {
          if (TempData["BError"] != null)
          {
                ModelState.AddModelError("error-key", "error-value");
          }
          ...
      }
}

public class BController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult BControllerAction()
      {
          try{Something();}
          catch(SomethingExceprion)
          {
              TempData["BError"] = true;
              return RedircetToAction("AControllerAction", "AController");
          }
      }
}
```

Comment: TempData is property of `ControllerBase` class, so I can pass data this way only between actions of the same controller but not between several controllers.

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavsky Just double-checked a recent project of mine. There doesn't seem to be any issue using it across controllers.

Comment: Although I must admit, I do like (and have used) the [solution proposed by Forty-Two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14199707/866022).

Comment: Well, thanks. I'm surprised that this method really works. I thought TempData will work only within one controller.

Comment: It works for the next request within a session. Adding a link about it.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what details of the exception you need to pass back to Controller A, I would do something along the lines of

```
public ActionResult BControllerAction()
{
     try{Something();}
     catch(SomethingException ex)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("AControllerAction", "AController", new { errorMessage = ex.Message() })
     }
}
```

And then change the signature of the called method to

```
public ActionResult AControllerAction(string errorMessage)
      {
          if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage))
          {
                //do something with the message
          }
          ...
      }
```