# How to call MVC Action using Jquery AJAX and then submit form in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On my MVC View I have button:

```
<input id="btnSave" type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" />
```

When I click this button I need call one Action, do some stuff there and then Submit my form.

I have this jQuery:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SaveDetailedInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Then I want to submit my form. In Controller I have 2 Actions:

```
public ActionResult SaveDetailedInfo(Option[] Options)
{
    return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Success" });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{ 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The problem is when I have `type="submit"` in my button, I can't reach `SaveDetailedInfo` Action, cause ajax gives me `error`, but when I remove `type="submit"`, ajax works fine, but `Save` Action never executes.

Please, any ideas how to execute both Actions? I thought maybe after `Ajax > Success` try to add `type=submit` through jquery and use `.click()`, but it sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` to stop the event of submit button and in ajax call success submit the form using `submit()`:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button
    var element = this;    
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SaveDetailedInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
                $(element).closest("form").submit(); //<------------ submit form
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. Now I can reach Home/SaveDetailedInfo, but when I submit form, I can't get into Save() Action

Comment: make sure ajax call is returning successfully put alert in success call back to verify

Comment: I changed submit() code and now it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you changed @Bryuk

Comment: $(element).closest("form").submit();

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your button is in a form, you are not preventing the default behaviour of the button click from happening i.e. Your AJAX call is made in addition to the form submission; what you're very likely seeing is one of

1. the form submission happens faster than the AJAX call returns
2. the form submission causes the browser to abort the AJAX request and continues with submitting the form.

So you should prevent the default behaviour of the button click

```
$('#btnSave').click(function (e) {

    // prevent the default event behaviour    
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/SaveDetailedInfo",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Options': someData}),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            // perform your save call here

            if (data.status == "Success") {
                alert("Done");
            } else {
                alert("Error occurs on the Database level!");
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. Now I can reach Home/SaveDetailedInfo, but when I submit form, I can't get into Save() Action

Answer (score 2):

Your C# action "Save" doesn't execute because your AJAX url is pointing to "/Home/SaveDetailedInfo" and not "/Home/Save".

To call another action from within an action you can maybe try this solution:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16870413/how-to-call-another-controller-action-from-a-controller-in-mvc)

Here's another better solution : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409049/net-mvc-call-a-controller-action-from-another-controller-action)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDetailedInfo(Option[] Options)
{
    return Json(new { status = "Success", message = "Success" });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{ 
    return RedirectToAction("SaveDetailedInfo", Options);
}
```

AJAX:

```
Initial ajax call url: "/Home/Save"
on success callback: 
   make new ajax url: "/Home/SaveDetailedInfo"
```

Comment: Action Save has the same name as Button name="Save" type="Submit", so when I click this button, I will get into [HttpPost] ActionResult Save()

Comment: don't use `<input type="submit"..>` . try `<button id="btnSave">Save</button>` your javascript will trigger on btnSave click.

Comment: After SaveDetailedInfo Action I need submit this form

Comment: Then in your ajax success callback, evaluate if data.status == "Success" then grab your form field values and build a new json object with it and do a new AJAX call.

Comment: It's true, but I believe that there is better way to get into Save() ActionResult, and work with Model and other MVC Stuff